# How to create multiple row report in Seagate Crystal Report Software

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-8.5

I am working with Seagate Crystal Report Software. After having designed the report, I am facing a typical problem that needs to be addressed. Suppose I have multiple values in one column, seperated by a ','(comma). I need to display it in multiple rows. How do I go about doing that. Eg :

Table name : **Student**
[image: the student table from which report needs to be generated]

The report should look like this : 
[image]

I know the basics of creating a report. So you can skip all that details while answering. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have achieved the desired layout by using line feed(`Chr(10)+Chr(13)`) as delimiter instead of Comma. That way, I do not need to make any change in Crystal Report. My purpose is achieved, but the solution to the original Question is pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula field named 'subjects':

```
// {@subjects}
Replace( {table.subject}, ",", Chr(10)+Chr(13) )
```

Add this field to the `details` section.

You could also create a SQL-Expression field:

```
// {%subjects}
(
  REPLACE( subject, ',', CHR(10)||CHR(13) )
)
```

Comment: When I add this formula in the respective attribute in my table, it gives an error saying 
"Result of selection formula must be a boolean"